# Calculate x y coordinates of a D3 tree/digraph

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, math, graph, tree

I am using D3.js Force Layout to draw a tree (with multiple parents making it a digraph). I have my set of nodes and links however i need to calculate the x y coordinates of the nodes manually. How can i calculate the coordinates correctly? I can have my starting coordinates fixed(for eg. 100,100). I have my links data which tells me the source and target along with the level it currently is at.

```
Source | SourceLvl | Target | TargetLvl
   0   |     0     |    1   |     1
   0   |     0     |    2   |     1
   0   |     0     |    3   |     1
   1   |     1     |    4   |     2
   1   |     1     |    5   |     2
   2   |     1     |    5   |     2
   2   |     1     |    6   |     2
   5   |     2     |    7   |     3
```

The graph could look something like below (node 5 as an example having multiple parents)

```
        0
      / |  \
    1   2   3
    /\  /\
   4  5   6
      |
      7
```

Comment: A force diagram for a tree isn't ideal, d3 offers functions for positioning/layouts of [trees](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#tree) and hierarchical data. Out of curiosity, why must you manually calculate the positions?

Comment: I cannot use the tree layout as my node can have multiple parent nodes(even multi level for that matter). Hence i am using the force layout with fixed node positions to draw the nodes. Also i dont want diagonal lines drawn between nodes for which i have written my own function to draw horizontal and vertical lines. I was able to draw one with hard coded x y coordinates for a simple diagram, but need to calculate the co ordinates for an actual structure

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for clarifying